# Python Django: How can multiple objects of one model belong to one and only one object of other model in django

Tags: django, python-2.7

What relationship should we use to **make multiple objects of one model and relate them to one and only one object of other model.**

Example:
A student can belong to only one school but a school can have multiple students.

The students can be created, added and are visible on the same admin page as that of the school i.e. **When a school object is created via admin panel I can create a student object from the same form i.e. of the school creation form of admin panel.**
Also on the admin page of school only the students which are related with that school should be visible not students of other schools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have foreign key on `Student` pointing to `School`:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)

class School(models.Model):
    pass
```

Check django doc about [many-to-one relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/).

In fact, it's not a django specific thing, it's relational database design. You should read some basics about relational database design to learn more about relation, normal forms, etc. That would help you understand better of your current situation(google would give you tons of resource).